# A Single or Multiple HTML codebases when using Google AMP?

Tags: html, amp-html

I'm using the same HTML for my regular webpages and the [Google AMP project](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml) webpages on this website: http://www.tribunadabahia.com.br/

I followed the instructions on Github, but I'm not quite sure if using the same HTML is the best practice.

Answer (score 6):

You need to:

- Create a separate AMP version of the page
- Link to it using `<link rel="amphtml" href="..."/>`
- Make sure it validates (using `#development=1` and looking for errors in the console)

To achieve those you can probably re-use a significant amount your original HTML, removing or replacing any invalid elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean when you say you're "using the same HTML" for AMP and regular webpages, since the AMP page will need the AMP JS library, AMP HTML components (such as the replacement tags), etc. in order to properly function as an AMP webpage. In fact, you don't even need to replace your non-AMP page if you don't want to (if that's what you were thinking), you can keep it and refer to it in your AMP page using the `<link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL" />` tag (see the "Required mark-up" section of [this](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/docs/create_page.md) page). I think having an AMP page that refers back to the regular page would be best just in case certain browsers don't work with with AMP pages yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In this case, I think it would be better to have different HTML for each, because I haven't replaced any regular HTML tags for AMP HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are many restrictions to AMP pages and the tags that they can use. Iframe tags and up until recently form tags could not be used in AMP pages. AMP supplies tags to use in place of some of these. Examples:

```
IFRAME --> AMP-IFRAME
IMG --> AMP_IMG 
VIDEO --> AMP-VIDEO
```

AMP really breaks down to having a "lighter" version of your main page in existence. To better explain you'll have an amp-canonical tag in your regular page which tells google that there is an AMP version. Your AMP version will then have a canonical pointing back to your regular page. If the AMP canonical exist in the regular page, google will server up the AMP version instead.

So when you're building these pages out, you can certainly reuse the HTML from your regular pages, just be aware that you'll most likely need to modify some of the tags in the page to meet AMP requirements. Also any CSS that is needed from your regular pages will need to be pulled out and put directly into the AMP page via the  tag.

The best suggestion I can make to you right now is do as much reading on AMP as possible before starting in. It's much less painful that way.

AMP Project: [read here](https://www.ampproject.org/)

Awesome Resource: [read here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/everything-about-google-accelerated-mobile-pages/)

Hope this helps!